# How to login with Digits User of Twitter kit in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Digits User of Twitter kit in IOS app.

but I am getting the following error now.

Guest authentication failed:

> Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=200 "Request failed: forbidden
>   (403)" UserInfo=0x7fccca7e1850
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/guest/activate.json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403),
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Forbidden. (code 200)}
>   [Twitter] Your app may not be enabled for guest authentication. Please
>   contact support@fabric.io to upgrade your consumer key. Digits error:
>   Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=215 "Request failed: bad
>   request (400)" UserInfo=0x7fccca6eede0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/device/register.json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400),
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Bad Authentication data.
>   (code 215)}

please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Without your code we can´t really help you!

Comment: [link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/digits)
I am using this code now.

Comment: I want to know what code YOU are using, not what the documentation says you should be using.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
  DGTAuthenticateButton *digitsButton =
        [DGTAuthenticateButton buttonWithAuthenticationCompletion:^
        (DGTSession *session, NSError *error) {
      // Inspect session/error objects
  }];
  [self.view addSubview:digitsButton];
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list/54838712#54838712

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem
You should use keys generated by Fabric. Go to your Fabric dashboard -> Digits

Use those keys in your app

Answer (score 0):

I had this error just in one device. Testing same app in other device, with the same iOS version and in the simulator didn't get any error.

Uninstalling the app and installing it again was the solution.